# get string between php cannot make it work

Tags: php

```
{"address":"18YtomFeRN8cu9h2pEBnpfNydAygpBhDug","label":"Fokke"}
```

How to use curl and get_string_between to get the address here (by address I mean `18YtomFeRN8cu9h2pEBnpfNydAygpBhDug`)?

I am using this code:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end)
{

    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}
$temp = curl_init($url);
$_SESSION['BTC_Address'] = get_string_between($temp, 'address":"', '"');
```

But it's not working, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data in question is [JSON](http://json.org/), a well-defined data format. Rather than trying to parse it manually, just use PHP's built-in [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function:

```
$json = json_decode($temp, true);
echo $json['address']; // echoes '18YtomFeRN8cu9h2pEBnpfNydAygpBhDug'
```

Passing `true` as the second parameter to `json_decode` decodes JSON objects to PHP associative arrays, which is usually what you want.